# After an update, OS won't let me override the default keyboard layout to my language preferences

Tags: keyboard, catalina

I have an Arteck HB086 bluetooth keyboard that I bought in the UK. I generally type in American English and MacOS's regional settings are U.S.

Until today, the keyboard worked with US-standard key mappings even though the keys are printed with UK-standard keys. For example, on the UK keyboard the @ is to the right of the colon instead of the single/double-quote button; on a US keyboard, @ is on the numeral 2.

- My input source is still set to US-english -- https://share.getcloudapp.com/Z4uyqxpp
- The keyboard type is set as US-ANSI.

I've re-paired, re-booted, etc. In other words, my system settings no longer seem to override the physical keyboard settings. The keys are still showing up as the UK mappings in both MacOS and Windows (I'm dual-boot). Again, I changed nothing today; something must have updated and now it doesn't work and I can no longer effectively type. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried a safe boot?  Sounds like perhaps a cache issue.

Comment: Have you tried the 're-recognise' app in Keyboard prefs, "Change Keyboard type"? It sounds like it's being recognised as UK ISO not ANSI [only UK PCs have @ on the right, UK Macs have it above 2, like US]. Also check what character you get on the key left of number 1.

Comment: I will try safe boot, thanks for the suggestion. I have indeed tried re-recognize and selected ANSI; agree that it seems to be operating as UK ISO.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I ran into the same problem today and think I found a fix (leaving this out for anybody who stumbles into this thread later).

The problem was to do with the different modes on the keyboard. My keyboard, under q, w, and e (in blue, fn key), has iOS, Android, and Win as optional buttons to press. It seems the keyboard had defaulted to the wrong version, possibly due to running out of battery. I struggled with this for a few hours, before it turned out that pressing Fn+e (Win) resulted in the keyboard returning to its UK layout and behaving normally. I believe it was on the iOS setting, which defaults to a US keyboard for some bizarre reason.

Hope this helps (although I realise this is now long in the past).